# Mongodb compound index for query and sorting

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I want use this query:

```
db.getCollection("collection").find({ 
    ownerId: ObjectId('63983ccaee2908fb7490fc6c'), 
    status: { $ne: 'REJECTED' }, 
    username: { $regex: 'a', $options: 'i' } }
).sort({ role: 1, username: 1 });
```

What is the correct compound index?
I use this index:

```
LeagueUserSchema.index({ username: 'text' });

LeagueUserSchema.index({
  ownerId: 1,
  status: 1,
  role: 1,
  username: 1,
});
```

but with *explain* I see this:

```
"winningPlan" : { "stage" : "FETCH", "inputStage" : { "stage" : "SORT", "sortPattern" : { "role" : 1.0 }, "memLimit" : 3.3554432E7, "limitAmount" : 10.0, "type" : "default", "inputStage" : { "stage" : "IXSCAN", "filter" : { "username" : { "$regex" : "a", "$options" : "i" } }, "keyPattern" : { "leagueId" : 1.0, "userId" : 1.0, "status" : 1.0, "role" : 1.0, "username" : 1.0 }, "indexName" : "leagueId_1_userId_1_status_1", "isMultiKey" : false, "multiKeyPaths" : { "leagueId" : [  ], "userId" : [  ], "status" : [  ], "role" : [  ], "username" : [  ] }, "isUnique" : false, "isSparse" : false, "isPartial" : false, "indexVersion" : 2.0, "direction" : "forward", "indexBounds" : { "leagueId" : [ "[ObjectId('63983ccaee....
```

Comment: The explain seems to show it is using an index for that query, what is your question?

Comment: "stage" : "SORT" is correct? shouldn't it be IXSCAN?

Answer (score 0):

The explain output shows that instead of the index you mention, the index being used for that query is:

```
{
 "leagueId" : 1, 
 "userId" : 1, 
 "status" : 1, 
 "role" : 1, 
 "username" : 1 
}
```

Check in mongosh to make sure the index you mentioned actually exists.

If it does, run explain with the "allPlansExecution" option so you can compare performance of the indexes.